# Convert Azure VM to Cloud Service

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We are putting up a asp.net webapi project on azure. It also does a few other things so it couldnt go up as an azure website. Our IT guy set it up on a Azure Virtual machine.

I've read we'd be more beneficial to run it as a cloud service (cost wise and also maintenance wise).

I'm just wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to convert an azure virtual machine to an azure cloud service?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't really convert an Azure VM into an Azure Cloud Service. What you could do is deploy your application as a cloud service. Once everything's working well, you can then deploy that application into a cloud service.

Comment: @deceze I'm curious....I got 2 downvotes because of inappropriate link? :(. I answered this question like 4 years ago and at that time the link was OK.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it unfortunately. Can you dig up some new reference, or preferably expand on the information within the post without relying on external references? That would probably get your answer voted up again.

Comment: Thanks @deceze. Let me see what I can do. Now I understand why link only answers are looked down upon here :).